# How to round to an arbitrary (non power-of-ten) precision

Tags: algorithm, rust, rounding, pseudocode

Let’s imagine I would like to round a number (i.e `x = 7.4355`) to a given arbitrary precision (i.e `p = 0.002`). In this case, I would expect to see:

```
round_arbitrary(x, p) = 7.436
```

What would be the best approach to design such a rounding function? Ideas in pseudocode or Rust are welcome

Comment: Divide by the precision, round to nearest integer, and multiply again?

Comment: Note that this is not a well-defined operation for binary floating-point numbers. The number `0.002` cannot be exactly represented as a IEEE 754 floating-point number, so the precision is a rounded value to start with. If you then try to round a number to that rounded precision, you will get unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

> What would be the best approach to design such a rounding function?

An approach that gets near to OP's goal:

```
// Pseudo code (p != 0)
round_arbitrary(x, p)
  x /= p
  x = round(x)
  return x*p
```

A key point is that floating point numbers are finite in size and so can represent about 2<sup>64</sup> different values exactly whereas code values like  7.4355, 0.002 and the math quotient 1/7.0 are of a *much* bigger set.  Thus the above will get one *close*, but not certainty to an *exact* mathematically rounded value.

More advanced code would avoid overflow by not rounding large values which do not need rounding.

```
// Assume 0 < |p| < 1.0 
round_arbitrary_2(x, p)
  if (round(x) != x)
    x /= p
    x = round(x)
    x *= p;
  return x*p
```

**Deeper**

This issues lies with floating point numbers that are encoded with an integer times a power-of-2.  Then the question is not so much "How to round to an arbitrary (non power-of-ten) precision", but "How to round to an arbitrary (non power-of-2) precision".